# In C# .NET, how do you access a property of an object when you know another property of an object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object with 2 properties, and I would like the user to select the object based on the name, and then use the rate associated with the object for a calculation, however I also use the name in the calculation in an 'if' statement. I have tried several things that have not worked because the name goes null in the middle of my app.

First, I tried to do a selectlist with multiple values so that when the user selected the object by name, the rate would be selected with it, but that ran into problems with it going null and I could never figure out why so I scrapped that.

Then I tried to do a switch statement that would set the rate based on the name, but it would go null again and not work so I've commented it out in my code.

Now, I'm going to try a 3rd thing where I use the name property to access the rate property, but I can't figure out how to do that.

For code examples, here is the object:

```
namespace MyCoolCalculator.MyCoolClasses
{
    public class County
    {
        public string CountyName { get; set; }
        public decimal CountyRate { get; set; }
        public County()
        {
        }
    }
    public static class CountyList
    {
        public static readonly List<County> Counties = new List<County>
        {
  new County {CountyName = "Cool County on the Shore", CountyRate = 0.0320M},
```

So if I can get the CountyName based on the user selecting it from a drop down list, is there a way to access the CountyRate just by knowing the CountyName?
And I do realize it would be so much more elegant if my first idea worked where there's multiple values in the selectlist like this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2
but it would go null so it wouldn't work for my calculation.

Comment: Wouldn't you just search `CountyList.Where(x => x.CountyName == "County Name Selected by User").Select(x => x.CountyRate).FirstOrDefault();`  You could make an AJAX call after the user selects the County Name, and return the rate.  Or, store the rate as a data-attribute on the `select` option and access the data-attribute via JavaScript / jQuery

Comment: I just tried this and got an error saying CS0117 CountyList has no definition for Where

Comment: Sorry, the name of your list is Counties, not CountyList.  So, `Counties.Where...`

Comment: You're going to want a reference to System.Linq. Devlin's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //use linq to find the element that matches the property value
            County county = CountyList.countyList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountyName.Equals("shore"));
            Console.WriteLine(county);
           
        }
    }

    public class County
    {
        public string CountyName { get; set; }
        public decimal CountyRate { get; set; }
        public County()
        {
        }
    }
    public static class CountyList
    {
        public static readonly List<County> countyList = new List<County>()
        {
            new County { CountyName = "shore", CountyRate=0.0320M},
            new County { CountyName = "beach", CountyRate=0.0420M},
            new County { CountyName = "country", CountyRate=0.0520M},
        };
    }
```